# Make pointer dereference safe

Tags: pointers, visual-c++, nullpointerexception

We work on a fairly large VC++ code base which has a central entity, lets say `class MainObject` and it is created in large numbers in one central place as,
`new MainObject()` and the reference(its address) to it is shared among many different objects. I am trying to delete the `MainObject` objects which will no longer be of use. Since a lot of objects hold this guy's reference they by chance might dereference it causing a crash. Is there a way that I can hide this object's raw pointer behind something(say something like a smart pointer, or similar) in the place its created and make random derefernces safe? Or realloc the object to a smaller size instead of deleting it? Or something? Is there something I can do?

TIA

Comment: It sounds like you may be looking for [`std::shared_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr)

Comment: Oh ok.. how can I use it to protect the random dereference?

Comment: If we have a shared_ptr if there are references to the pointer somewhere, it would not deleted right? I am trying reduce memory consumption by unused objects here primarily.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "random dereference". If you use `shared_ptr` throughout, you'll make sure that an instance of `MainObject` is not deleted for as long as someone is still holding a pointer to it.

Comment: Well, if someone holds a (smart) pointer to an object, then that object is not "unused", by definition.

Comment: I would like to delete the object and remove references to it from anybody. What I mean is, since the code base is large, there might be someone who should not be holding the main object's reference, but is holding one, which by itself is a mistake. I want to be able to remove the references and then the object too.

Comment: You might be interested in [`std::weak_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/weak_ptr). It works in conjunction with `std::shared_ptr`, but doesn't keep the object alive. A strong `shared_ptr` can be obtained from it as needed, if the object is still alive (by way of someone else holding a strong reference).